# Should pkg_resources.DefaultProvider work with namespace packages?

Tags: python, jinja2, setuptools, pkg-resources

I have a namespace package, and in one of the packages in that namespace I have a `Jinja2` template. I am using `jinja2.PackageLoader` to load it.

However, if I create a `jinja2.PackageLoader('namespacepackage')` and then try to `list_templates()`, it fails to find the `templates/` folder, and I can see why:

It creates a `pkg_resources.DefaultProvider('namespacepackage')` and then uses its `resource_listdir()` method, giving it `'templates'` as argument.
But `resource_listdir()` joins this path with `self.module_path` internally, and `self.module_path` is set from the module's `__path__` attribute:

```
self.module_path = os.path.dirname(getattr(module, '__file__', ''))
```

Since `namespacepackage` has no `__file__`, `DefaultProvider.module_path` is set to `''`, and the template lookup in Jinja fails.

**How is this supposed to work?
Aren't I supposed to provide the package name to `PackageLoader`?**
If I refer to a specific `namespacepackage.module`, everything works, because the module has a `__file__`, so `DefaultProvider.module_path` is set correctly.